# Using pointer-to-derived on a base class object, which overridden methods are called?

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived-class

I have a situation that I *thought* was going to cause problems but now I'm not so sure.

The code I'm looking at has a base and derived class with a method in the base that is over-ridden in the derived. It creates a base object and static casts that to the derived type:

```cpp
Derived *d = static_cast< Derived * >( new Base( x, y, z ) );
d->overridden_method();
```

I *thought* that calling the overridden method in that case would result in the *base* class method being executed as the underlying object itself is of that class, and therefore the vtable entry would reference the base class function.

However, it looks like the *derived* method is being called in this case. Is that expected?

There's plenty of stuff I've found regarding going the other way (casting derived to base) but I've come up short trying to find any information on this scenario. Calling the overridden function on a base class pointer will, I believe, call the derived method. Otherwise, something like this wouldn't work, surely:

```cpp
for ( const auto &shape : shapes ) {
    shape.draw();  // Handles any sort of derived shape.
}
```

---

By the way, before you state that we *shouldn't* be doing the cast to derived, be aware it's code we've inherited and we're actually trying to fix this issue (or non-issue if I'm wrong).

However, when I created a unit test to illustrate the problem (so I'd know when I'd fixed it), it looks like there *is* no problem. Hence this question.

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Comment: Related: [c++ - converting a base class pointer to a derived class pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18874064/12002570) and [static_cast from base class pointer to derived class pointer is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011458/static-cast-from-base-class-pointer-to-derived-class-pointer-is-invalid) or [Why is a static_cast from a Pointer to Base to a Pointer to Derived "invalid?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808758/why-is-a-static-cast-from-a-pointer-to-base-to-a-pointer-to-derived-invalid)

Comment: @WeijunZhou: if you're going to state that, it's probably better in an answer. and with the ISO reference to support it :-)

Comment: A [mcve] would be better than a hundred words.

Comment: Dupe: [Does this downcasting lead to undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71505316/does-this-downcasting-lead-to-undefined-behavior)

Comment: Usually when you have to cast to a derived class it means you have a design issue. What you see is exactly what should happen. Calling a virtual method on a class through its base class pointer should result in calling the method on the derived class.

Comment: While I was putting together a minimal reproducible example, it actually did what I expected. That leads me to believe that the accepted answer is actually correct and that I was doing UB. So, given the question's closed as a dupe, there's little reason for me to add that example. Thanks for your help, people, appreciate it.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: wasn't so much a design issue as it was inexperienced developers, I suspect :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I suspected that too, more of an advance kind of warning never to look at downcasting ever again (at least not as first, second or even third option) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting a pointer that actually points to a (complete) base object to a derived type is undefined behavior. Quote from [expr.static.cast](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#12)(emphasis mine)

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B”, where B is a class type, can be
> converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 D”, where D is a
> complete class derived from B, if cv2 is the same cv-qualification as,
> or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. If B is a virtual base class of
> D or a base class of a virtual base class of D, or if no valid
> standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists
> ([conv.ptr]), the program is ill-formed. The null pointer value
> ([basic.compound]) is converted to the null pointer value of the
> destination type. **If the prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B” points to
> a B that is actually a base class subobject of an object of type D,
> the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type D.
> Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

Your pointer does not point to a valid base-class subobject, hence the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, it looks like I will have to modify the code so that the underlying object is the derived class rather than the base class. I just couldn't figure out why it seemed to work in my test case. But, in trying to create a minimal example, I found that *didn't* work there, it instead called the base class methods always. That means it's almost certainly to do with the fact that UB sometime s seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: @user12002570 That is different. It is valid to perform the cast if it actually points to a base class subobject, as is in the case of CRTP. It doesn't matter where you perform the cast. But it is illegal to cast if it points to a complete object of base, as in the case of `static_cast<Derived*>(new Base(...));`.